# With ANTLR4 Parser: How to skip parsing RULE after new line (hidden token)

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm trying to implement a rule for javadoc/comments where javadoc can be placed either on the line before the field or right after in the same line (like in JHipster JDL)

```
entity A {
  firstField String
  /** name javadoc */
  name String
  count Integer /** count javadoc */
}
```

This is what the rule looks like:

```
field: javadoc? annotations field_name field_type (field_validations)* suffix_javadoc?
```

But because new line tokens are ignored, javadoc is always being parsed as suffix_javadoc.

In this example "name javadoc" ends up in firstField.

I would like to skip the rule `suffix_javadoc` after a new line token

**Clarification:** in the example above both are "doc comments", my problem is how to build a parse-tree that takes into account that "entity fields" are separated by a new-line character, so after a new line came a new field not a suffix_javadoc.

Digging into the code I got this working, but it feels very hacky.

```
@parser::members {
    public Token match(int ttype) throws RecognitionException {
        try { // hack to not parse suffix javadoc after new lines (hidden tokens)
            if(getRuleContext() instanceof Suffix_javadocContext) {
                System.out.println("RULE_suffix_javadoc");
                int currentTokenIndex = getCurrentToken().getTokenIndex();
                var prevToken = getTokenStream().get(currentTokenIndex - 1);
                if(prevToken.getText().contains("\n")) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return super.match(ttype);
    }
}
```

Is there a proper/better way to achieve this?

Comment: There’s a difference between Javadoc and regular comments. Javadoc _always_ precedes the definition that is being documented (class or method). What you showed are actually comments that use invalid syntax, those should use `//` or `/* */` instead.

Comment: This grammar is not for parsing Java but JHipster 'like' JDL files (see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#commenting). The example I posted is the right syntaxis. Btw `javadoc` and `suffix_javadoc` rules are identical in content.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse semantics with syntax. A comment being JavaDoc or not is a semantic decision! So my advice is to parse without explicit `javaDoc` rules, but put all comments on a hidden channel (like almost all grammars do). Then, in your semantic phase (which follows the syntax phase, where you parsed your input) walk through the hidden channel tokens, compare their position to other tokens in the default channel and decide then based on that comparison if this comment is to be considered as normal comment or as doc comment.

Comment: hi @mike for your answer. Just to be clear, in my example both *are* docs. I dont' have problem distinguising comments from docs and yes comments go to the hidden channel but docs don't (like in the antlr4 grammar itself, which I use a lot as example for building the IntelliJ plugin). My problem is with where the parser places the docs hanging from. For what I'm reading, the semmantic phase is the tree-walking listener, but the tree would be already 'wrong', and I need the tree to be also correct for IntelliJ plugin related staff.. Thanks anyway